# WebPage works if opened manualy. Returns "Window language could not be determined" if opened via Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am dealing with a small problem. I am working on automating few tasks in a web application,i can open the webpage,enter the login,click login,BUT then it starts to act strange. If i click on the login manualy it logs in without a problem. 
But if i try to do it via selenium (JAVA jdk1.7.0_75,selenium-java-2.53.1,running on IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0) the page opens with error An error has occured.
 java.lang.NullPointerException. and with "Window language could not be determined  "

The page is on the intranet. I guess the application has a problem with the Webdriver (everything works if i try to automate the task using the VBS). 
Dont you know any "workaround" for that?

(I can use only IE,because chrome no longer supports NPAPI so the application does not work in chrome)

```
InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("*the webpage*");
        driver.findElementByName("userid").sendKeys("*login*");
        driver.findElementByName("password").clear();
        driver.findElementByName("password").sendKeys("*password*");
        driver.findElementByName("ctr").sendKeys("*number*");
        driver.findElementByName("menuType").click();
        driver.findElementByLinkText("OK").click();
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the settings,because as i mentioned,if o open the browser manualy and login,it works,no errors and i get into the app.

But the webdriver "browser" has somehow different settings (i think) so it does not work. Problem is,that we have restricted access to the settings of browser,so i cant do much about that.

Thank you very much for any suggestions/answers/tips!!

Kind Regards,
Jerry Woodburn

Comment: can you post selenium code here . Edit your question please

Comment: Is there a possibility of bumping up Selenium to v3.4.0 with IEDriverServer 3.4 with IE-10/11 ?

Comment: Use latest selenium and try it

Comment: u dont need to clear password field because every time when you execute the script it will create a new browser node and it wont use any cache memory of existing browser session. Delete this line driver.findElementByName("password").clear();

Comment: Well,the problem is,that i have only jdk 1.7.0_75,i guess the new selenium version wont work with that. But i'll give it a try,see what happens...

Comment: Yes use java 1.8 and latest selenium version . I am damn sure that you wont face any problem if you are setting the environment right